# Add defined value in Doxygen documentation

Tags: ios, doxygen, c-preprocessor

I use Doxygen to document my code, but I can't find how to add the `#define` value in the documentation.
I tried this [found here](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Doxygen-for-multiple-defines-td493.html):

```
  /**
  * @brief test
  */
   #define definedValue @"aValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the defined value to appear in the documentation you can use the [\showinitializer](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdshowinitializer) command.   The documentation comment can also appear on the same line as the `#define` using:

```
#define definedValue @"aValue" /**< Description of defined variable */
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```objc
/**
 * \def definedValue
 *
 * @brief test
 */
#define definedValue @"aValue"
```

See also: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddef